# how to use LINQ with dynamic paramters in orderby clause

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, entity-framework-6, iqueryable

i have a problem to use the dynamic parameters inside orderby `linq` expression

1. SearchExp function

   ```
   public Expression<Func<EmailAflAwmMessageDM, bool>> SearchXpr(string param, string q)
   {
       if (param == "to")
           return e => e.to_msg.Contains(q);
       else if (param == "from")
           return e => e.from_msg.Contains(q);
       else if (param == "cc")
           return e => e.cc_msg.Contains(q);
       else if (param == "bcc")
           return e => e.bcc_msg.Contains(q);
       else if (param == "subject")
           return e => e.subject.Contains(q);
       else
           return e => e.body_text.Contains(q);
   }
   ```
2. filterExp function

   ```
      public Expression<Func<EmailAflAwmMessageDM, bool>> FiltertXpr(string filter, string value)
      {
       if (filter == "attachments")
       return e => e.attachments == value;
       else if (filter == "flagged")
       return e => e.flagged == value;
       else
       return e => e.seen == value;
       }
   ```
3. IQueryable function

   ```
      private IQueryable SearchFilter(string param,string q,string filter,
          string value,string sort,string dir)
      {
         var searchXpr = SearchXpr(param, q);
         var filterXpr = FiltertXpr(filter, value);
         var emailmessage = 
         db.EmailAflAwmMessage.
         Where(filterXpr).Where(searchXpr)
         .OrderByDescending(a => a.msg_date).Select(a =>
         new
         {
          a.subject,
          a.msg_date,
         });

          return emailmessage;
         }
   ```

The above code is working, but i need `OrderBy` in dynamic way.
as i have 2 parameters sort( mean its the parameter name ) and dir (mean ascending or descending) like i want orderby(parameter name) dir
please help me, i appreciate your valuable time and suggestion, and also suggest me any alternate with simple way. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to read about [Expression's tree's](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882637.aspx), the code bellow is for didatic , but I think that will help you:

```
  public static class ExpressionBuilder
    {
        private static readonly MethodInfo ToStringMethod = typeof(object).GetMethod("ToString");
        private static readonly MethodInfo StringContainsMethod = typeof(string).GetMethod("Contains");

        public static Func<T, object> Selector<T>(string prop)
        {
            var type = typeof(T);
            var param = Expression.Parameter(type);
            return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, object>>(Expression.Property(param, type.GetProperty(prop)), param).Compile();
        }

        public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> BuildFilterPredicate<T>(string q)
        {
            var query = Expression.Constant(q);
            var type = typeof(T);
            var lbdSelector = Expression.Parameter(type);
            var predicates = type.GetProperties().SelectMany(p => PredicateContainsBuilder(lbdSelector, p, query)).ToList();
            Expression body = predicates[0];
            body = predicates.Skip(1).Aggregate(body, Expression.OrElse);
            return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(body, lbdSelector);
        }

        private static IEnumerable<MethodCallExpression> PredicateContainsBuilder(Expression lbdSelector, PropertyInfo prop, Expression query)
        {

            if (prop.PropertyType.IsClass)
                return new List<MethodCallExpression> { Expression.Call(Expression.Call(Expression.Property(lbdSelector, prop), ToStringMethod), StringContainsMethod, query) };

            var properties = prop.PropertyType.GetProperties();
            return properties.Select(p => Expression.Call(Expression.Call(Expression.Property(lbdSelector, p), ToStringMethod), StringContainsMethod, query)).ToList();
        }
    }
```

So now you do this in your method:

> #### Note:
>
> - I supose that the entity is **EmailMessage** so i use that to generate the predicate;
> - It doesn't search in depth;
> - it will search in all properties and doesn't use the `string param` to define what property to match;

```
private IQueryable SearchFilter(string param,string q,string filter,string value,string sort,string dir)
    {
        var emailMessage = db.EmailAflAwmMessage
                            .Where(ExpressionBuilder.BuildFilterPredicate<EmailMessage>(q))
                            .OrderBy(ExpressionBuilder.Selector<EmailMessage>(sort))
                            .Select(m=> new{m.subject,m.msg_date});        
    return emailmessage;
    }
```

Comment: thanks for your answers, can you please read it again my question, what i need exactly. i need in where clause with 2 function 1 with param name and text as q for search and 2nd filter with param name and text with yes or no and 3rd one order by param name and sort order as well. thanks again

Comment: @adnan but the snippet show you the way to do that, and i suggested  a link to an article to you learn about and implement it as your needs.

Answer (score 1):

i have got the easy solution and now its working with me, there are more alternatives but i just to share my answer:

1. SortXpr function

   ```
    private IQueryable SortXpr(IQueryable<EmailAflAwmMessageDM> email ,string sort,string dir) {

       if (sort.Contains("to"))
       {
           if (dir.Contains("asc"))
           {
               return email.OrderBy(e => e.to_msg);
           }
           else
           {
               return email.OrderByDescending(e => e.to_msg);
           }
       }
       else if (sort.Contains("from"))
       {
           if (dir.Contains("asc"))
           {
               return email.OrderBy(e => e.from_msg);
           }
           else
           {
               return email.OrderByDescending(e => e.from_msg);
           }
       }
       else if (sort.Contains("subject"))
       {
           if (dir.Contains("asc"))
           {
               return email.OrderBy(e => e.subject);
           }
           else
           {
               return email.OrderByDescending(e => e.subject);
           }
       }
       else
       {
           if (dir.Contains("asc"))
           {
               return email.OrderBy(e => e.msg_date);
           }
           else
           {
               return email.OrderByDescending(e => e.msg_date);
           }
       }

   }
   ```
2. FilterXpr function

   ```
   private Expression<Func<EmailAflAwmMessageDM, bool>>    FiltertXpr(string filter, string value)
   {
       if (filter == "attachments")
           return e => e.attachments == value;
       else if (filter == "flagged")
           return e => e.flagged == value;
       else
           return e => e.seen == value;
   }
   ```
3. SearchXpr function

   ```
   private Expression<Func<EmailAflAwmMessageDM, bool>> SearchXpr(string param, string q)
   {
       if (param == "to")
           return e => e.to_msg.Contains(q);
       else if (param == "from")
           return e => e.from_msg.Contains(q);
       else if (param == "cc")
           return e => e.cc_msg.Contains(q);
       else if (param == "bcc")
           return e => e.bcc_msg.Contains(q);
       else if (param == "subject")
           return e => e.subject.Contains(q);
       else
           return e => e.body_text.Contains(q);
   }
   ```
4. SearchFilterCondition function

   ```
    private IQueryable SearchFilterCondition(string param,string q
       ,string filter,string value,string sort,string dir)
    {
      var searchXpr = SearchXpr(param, q);
      var filterXpr = FiltertXpr(filter, value);
      IQueryable<EmailAflAwmMessageDM>
      EmailAflAwmMessagejc = db.EmailAflAwmMessage.Where(filterXpr).Where(searchXpr);
      return SortXpr(EmailAflAwmMessagejc, sort, dir);
    }
   ```

thanks for the stackoverflow community, i appreciate your valuable time, thanks again.